# re.search only return part of strings

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, lxml, python-re

I want to use the Python `re` module to get contents between `<script>...</script>` tags.  I use `re.search(r'<script>[\S\s]*</script>', myhtml)` to search the content where `[\S\s]*` means search any string. But this function behaves strangely, it only returns part of the desired content. so I make a small example to show what I mean.

```
import re
re.search('[\S\s]*','<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E')
```

the desired result should be `'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E'` which is the original input string . however, it prints `<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 56), match='<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traiti>`. as can be seen , the last part of the string ,ie.`'onal//E'` is missing.

Why is that? How can I extract contents between tags?

Also, some may suggest I should use `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup` because I found strange things as well:

With this code:

```
from lxml import etree
rr='''
<script>
<div>
im here
</div>
</script>

'''
html = etree.HTML(rr, etree.HTMLParser())
print(html.xpath('//div//text()'))
```

The above code prints nothing.  If I change `<script>` to `<script1>`, then it prints `im here` as expected, and `BeautifulSoup` has the same behavior.

Comment: You are seeing a part of the match because the `__repr__` method of the `re.Match` class truncates the string for display purposes. Try `re.search(...).group(0)` to see the whole match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to [@Selcuk's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68370689/re-search-only-return-part-of-strings/68371115#comment120833806_68370689), you are doing `.search`, which returns the `re.Match` class, which has 0 to many groups of individual matches. These have more data, like the starting index of the match, and its length, than `.findall`.

```
>>> match = re.search('[\S\s]*','<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E')
>>> match
<re.Match object; span=(0, 56), match='<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traiti>
>>> dir(match)
['__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__copy__', '__deepcopy__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'end', 'endpos', 'expand', 'group', 'groupdict', 'groups', 'lastgroup', 'lastindex', 'pos', 're', 'regs', 'span', 'start', 'string']
```

You can also use `.findall()`, which will return a list.

I would also suggest always using r'' strings when passing regex patterns.

```
>>> re.search(r'[\S\s]*','<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E').group(0)
'<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E'
>>> re.findall(r'[\S\s]*','<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E')
['<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-<!DO/W3C//DTD C 1.0Traitional//E', '']
```

Comment: thanks!!! but why the lxml doesn't recongnize the tag?

Answer (score 1):

Your first question has already been addressed.

The answer to your second question:

> The above code prints nothing. If I change `<script>` to `<script1>`, then
> it prints `im here` as expected, and `BeautifulSoup` has the same
> behavior.

This is since the `<div>` is actually *within* the `<script>` tag.

With your provided HTML:

```html
<script>
<div>
im here
</div>
</script>
```

If we prettify it, you'll see clearly that the `<div>` tag is *within* the `<script>`:

```html
<script>
  <div>
  im here
  </div>
</script>
```

So, to get the `<div>`, using `BeautifulSoup`, you can use the [`next_element`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-element-and-previous-element) property:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
print(soup.find("script").next_element)
```

Output:

```
<div>
im here
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much !   but why is the case? i don't understand...

Comment: @user8641707 If you would do `soup.find('div')` it would return `None`, since there is no `div`, the `div` is _inside_ a `script`, so you need to find the `script`, not the `div`. Understand?